# Typescript type of e.currentTarget on a (mouseenter) event

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, events

HTML:

```
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        routerLink="about"
        (mouseenter)="onLinkHover($event)"
        >About</a
      >
    </li>
```

TypeScript:

```
  onLinkHover(e: any) {
    this.isHoverMenuOpen = true;

    if (this.isHoverMenuOpen && !e.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach((link) => {
      if (e.currentTarget.innerHTML !== link.innerHTML) {
        link.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
  }
```

I have a working Angular code looks like above but I don't want to use "any" type for the event type. What's the proper type for this event in TypeScript?

Any type I tried was giving an error: **"Property 'currentTarget' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2339)"**

Comment: `e`'s type should be something like `MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>` or similar. (Sorry, I haven't done Angular for years.)

Comment: It says: "'MouseEvent' is not generic"

Comment: just use `MouseEvent` as the `e` type: `onLinkHover(e: MouseEvent)`

Comment: @armagansenol - Then just `MouseEvent` should be sufficient, although depending on how it's defined it may well only make `currentTarget` of type `Element`, not `HTMLElement`, and you need the latter to use `classList`. :-| Another option for you: `onLinkHover(e: {currentTarget: HTMLElement})`. (But I bet there's a more official and correct Angular way than that.)

Answer (score 1):

The Error is not because of `any` as a type. You can have it as required.

The Error is happening due the way CurrentTarget property works. You are referring it incorrectly somewhere as the error says `HTMLDivElement` but we don't see any div in the posted code.

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies
> the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It
> always refers to the element to which the event handler has been
> attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on
> which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

> The value of event.currentTarget is only available while the event is
> being handled. If you console.log() the event object, storing it in a
> variable, and then look for the currentTarget key in the console, its
> value will be null. Instead, you can either directly
> console.log(event.currentTarget) to be able to view it in the console
> or use the debugger statement, which will pause the execution of your
> code thus showing you the value of event.currentTarget.

More here :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: "any" works fine, yeah and there is no div element ok but any other type such as "HTMLElement" or "MouseEvent" also gives an error.